# Gulp task is not working

Tags: javascript, css, gulp, rename, minify

I want to minify and rename all my .css in the folder (../dist/css), but it says that there's an error (You can see the error in the screenshot below).

```
var gulp =         require('gulp');
var postcss =      require('gulp-postcss');
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
var lost =         require('lost');
var rucksack =     require('rucksack-css');
```

> ```
> var cssnano =      require('cssnano');
> var rename =       require('gulp-rename');
> ```

```
gulp.task('css', function() {
    var plugins = [
            autoprefixer({
                browsers: ['last 2 version']
            }),
            rucksack({
                quantityQueries: false,
                alias: false,
                easings: false,
                inputPseudo: false
            }),
            lost
    ];
    return gulp.src('app/styles/**/*.css')
        .pipe(postcss(plugins))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css'));
});
```

> //========THIS PART IS NOT WORKING============
>
> ```
>  gulp.task('css-min', ['css'], function() {
>   return gulp.src('app/styles/*.css')
>       .pipe(cssnano())
>       .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
>       .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css')); });
> ```

```
gulp.task('watch', ['css', 'css-min'], function() {
        gulp.watch('app/styles/**/*.css', ['css']);
});

 gulp.task('default', ['watch']);
```

[image]

Comment: Missed the screenshot ?

Comment: may be your path not working, try using this: `.pipe(gulp.dest('./css'));`

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aX5eF.png

Comment: @ManishPatel, path is working properly

Comment: @user1428716 it's OK now

Comment: Did you make a change?

Comment: Did you miss - var dest = require('gulp-dest');

Comment: @Mark yes, I did it

Comment: @user1428716 what do you mean?

Comment: npm install gulp-dest ?